# sonarlint warning about parameters in a switch expression with tuples not being used

Tags: c#, switch-statement, sonarlint, c#-8.0

I'm having a weird problem regarding sonarlint (visual studio extension) not identifying a method's parameters as being used if they're used in a tuple of a switch expression (new c# 8 feature). Here is a piece of code to demonstrate:

```
private bool Xor(bool A, bool B) 
{ 
    return (A, B) switch
    {
        (false, false) => false,
        (true, false) => true,
        (false, true) => true,
        (true, true) => false,
    };
}
```

If I compile this code I get the following code smell:

> "Remove this parameter 'A', whose value is ignored in the method" for both parameters

But the method clearly works as intended. Weirdly enough, this only happens with a private method

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an unexpected behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in sonarlint. It can of course take some time, before addons are updated to recognize new language features properly. The reason language features take that long to deploy, is because catching all those special cases takes a time. | However your implementation looks slightyl different from the example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#tuple-patterns

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know enough about how this syntax sugar is translated to real code, to tell if it makes a difference.

Comment: @bootzin Have you tried to make your method expression-bodied? And change the variable names to lower case?

Comment: Yes, I did.. As a matter of fact, this is just a repro method I created to demonstrate, the original one has lower case variable names and is expression bodied.. It also has the default fallback.. I didn't post the original one here though because it is switched over the value of two enums, with 4 items on each, making it quite a huge list to put in here